# Pdfbox why can't I load a document?

Tags: java, maven, pdf, undefined, pdfbox

So I'm having trouble loading a PDDocument when using PDDocument.load(File). I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the jars for PDFBox to see if the PDDocument object would render properly. Still not working, and I'm very unsure why. The PDDocument object seems to only have its instance methods rather than its documented static methods. I only have a runtime error of NoSuchMethodError regarding PDDocument.load(file).

Here is my code:

```
package main;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File f = new File("C:/Users/user/Desktop/sample/Resume_Michael_Sinclair.pdf");
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(f);
        
        PDFTextStripper tp = new PDFTextStripper();
        System.out.println(tp.getText(doc));
        doc.close();
    }
}
```

pom.xml is what is used to render the pdfbox objects to my understanding, so here is my pom.xml if that helps:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Pdfeasy_Editor</groupId>
  <artifactId>Pdfeasy_Editor</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
  <build>
      <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
               <source>1.8</source>
               <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration> 
         </plugin>
      </plugins> 
   </build> 
   
   <dependencies>  
      <dependency> 
         <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId> 
         <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId> 
         <version>2.0.1</version> 
      </dependency>   
   
      <dependency> 
         <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId> 
         <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId> 
         <version>2.0.0</version> 
      </dependency>
      
      <dependency>  
         <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId> 
         <artifactId>jempbox</artifactId> 
         <version>1.8.11</version> 
      </dependency> 
        
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId> 
         <artifactId>xmpbox</artifactId> 
         <version>2.0.0</version> 
      </dependency> 
     
      <dependency> 
         <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId> 
         <artifactId>preflight</artifactId> 
         <version>2.0.0</version> 
      </dependency> 
     
      <dependency> 
         <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId> 
         <artifactId>pdfbox-tools</artifactId> 
         <version>2.0.0</version> 
      </dependency>

   </dependencies>
   
</project>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :).

Comment: Please use pdfbox related artifacts with the same version. And do use a current version which should be around 2.0.22 nowadays.

Comment: "RC" stands for release candidate - so, not yet an official release. The latest official release in Maven is 2.0.23 for the PDFBox artifacts (and 1.8.16 for jempbox). Having said that, I cannot recreate your problem using these, or the versions in your question's POM. Works fine with Java 8 and Java 15. This suggests the problem may be more fundamental, and not directly related to the code in your question.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your responses! Problem solved, I needed the 2.0.23 jars like y'all said and changed the versions to 2.0.23 in the pom file.

Comment: I wonder, what made you use 2.0.0 and 2.0.1 in the first place?

Comment: Nothing aside from overlooking the pom file. I had used tutorialspoint's walkthrough of installing PDFBox in a project and they showcased the same pom file :D.

Comment: @MichaelSinclair You can now answer your own question, then other people know what the problem was...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was that my pom.xml file had the wrong versions of the libraries. PDFBox 3.0.0 didn't have full functionality for me, so I switched my libraries to the official build, 2.0.23. After setting all versions to 2.0.23, for example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox-tools</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.23</version>
</dependency>
```

This solved the problem, and the initial syntax I posted now works! Credit to @andrewjames and @mkl